# Indicating of some part of body with comparison

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

How to indicate correctly which part of your body you look like someone? For example: eyes

If we use "You look nothing like someone" then how to indicate what I wrote above?

> ?You look your eyes like your daddy?

> Your eyes look like daddy's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Your eyes look like Daddy's* would be acceptable. In my experience, the most idiomatic way to say it would be *You've got your daddy's eyes,* (obviously meaning *you have inherited the appearance of your eyes from your father.)*